# Database structure and sql for an Encyclopedia like "See Also" field

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to design a database that is similar to an encyclopedia/dictionary where there is a "See also" option.  I can do simple databases with multiple tables but I'm far from an expert.

So I made some sample data to try and figure it out but now I am stuck.

I am shooting for doing it in php/mysql so I can have web pages as the output but what I need help with is the db design and the sql to make the "see also" bit work right. I am thinking I need another table that somehow connects all of them but I’m not sure how to do that.

***Example Table Fields:***

**Table 1: Place**

- PlaceID PK
- PlaceName
- PlaceCityName
- PlaceStateName
- PlaceSeeAlso

**Table 2: Person**

- PersonID PK
- PersonName
- PersonJob
- PersonSeeAlso

**Table 3: Thing**

- ThingID PK
- ThingName
- ThingSeeAlso

***Example data:***

**Places Table**

```
00
PlaceA
Philadelphia
PA
PersonA, PersonB, ThingA, PlaceC

01
PlaceB
Philadelphia
PA
PersonA, ThingB, PlaceA, PlaceC

02
PlaceC
Philadelphia
PA
PersonA, ThingB, ThingC, PlaceA
```

***Person Table***

```
00
PersonA
Worker
ThingB, PlaceA, PlaceC

01
PersonB
Worker
PersonA, PersonC, ThingB, PlaceA, PlaceC

02
PersonC
Boss
PersonB, ThingB, ThingC, PlaceA, PlaceB
```

***Things Table***

```
00
ThingA
PersonA, PlaceC

01
ThingB
PersonB, PlaceB, ThingC

02
ThingC
PersonA, PersonC, PersonE, PlaceC, ThingA
```

So for example say you did a search for a person, place or thing, let’s say "PersonC", the output on a webpage/window in my program/whatever would be:

```
Name: PersonC
City: Philadelphia
State: PA
Description: Boss
See Also: PersonA, ThingB, ThingC, PlaceA
```

All of the things under "See Also" should be clickable to bring up the matching record. So in the above example you click "ThingC" you would get

```
Name: ThingC
See Also: PersonA, PersonC, PersonE, PlaceC, ThingA
```

All of the things under "See Also" should be clickable etc etc etc.

Just a reminder I am in need of help with how to structure the DB and maybe some of the sql as far as the See Also part is concerned, not the making things clickable on a webpage etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this kind of thing but I agree an extra table for the see also makes sense, though I dont think the see also column on your table should be necessary as you already have a unique identifier for each row on those tables.

A "linking" table would probably make sense here. For example,

SeeAlsoID int Primary Key, CurrentPageID, currentPageType, DestinationPageID, destinantionPageType

Then for each page you display you can have any number of rows linking to associated pages.

e.g. say personA has a personid of 1 and you want to show placeid 2 is associated with them and so is thingid 5 you would use two rows associated with the currentpageid1

Seealsoid,          currentpageid,        currentpagetype,        destinationpageid,     destinationpagetype

1,                          1,                               person,                         2,                                   place

2,                          1,                               person,                         5,                                   thing

apologies for what I anticipate will appear to be awful formatting, I am on a tablet which has very limited compatibility with SO.

Comment: I worked on what you posted above and it seems to be what I needed. thanks!